# Get current date in Dart

Tags: datetime, dart

How can I get the current date independent of system date and time in Dart?

I have tried `DateTime().now` but it gives system date not the actual date (in case system date is altered).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't trust the system to give the correct time you need to ask somewhere else to get the time. This can be done in multipe ways depending upon the accuracy you need. E.g. the easiest way would be to just call an HTTP server with an API to get the time from the server.

If the accuracy is important to you then you should use an NTP client to connect to multiple time sources (e.g. from ntppool.org). I can see there is a package for this here:
https://pub.dev/packages/ntp

I would say that in most cases you should just trust the OS. If a user want to manipulate the time he/she should be able to do that. And if the time accuracy is important you don't want to trust the client but use a accuracy from you own server.